# Is there a way to tell the browser to disable its built-in scroll-optimization?

Tags: javascript, html

When using event listeners such as touchstart, touchmove, mousewheel, etc. Chrome's developer console outputs a "Violation"-warning as such:

`[Violation] Added non-passive event listener to a scroll-blocking 'touchstart' event. Consider marking event handler as 'passive' to make the page more responsive. See https://www.chromestatus.com/feature/5745543795965952`

These violations ocur when the browser has to wait for the event handler to finnish/find out wether the handler calls event.preventDefault() and would therefore cancel scrolling. But what if the site doesn't need to be scrolled? Is there a way to tell the browser to completely disbale the built-in scroll-optimization and therefore prevent a violation and make the site more optimized?

I did find this code on [this site](https://www.uriports.com/blog/easy-fix-for-unable-to-preventdefault-inside-passive-event-listener/) :

```
window.addEventListener('touchstart', function() {
    // some logic
}, {passive:false}); // <-- mark the event listerner as NOT passive
```

But my touchstart listener is in an element

HTML:

```
 <button ontouchstart="showMenu(document,6); game = 'paused';" class="hidden pause-btn menu5">
    <image id="pause-btn-img" src="./assets/images/menu/pause.png" />
  </button>
```

JS:

```
function showMenu(DOM, id) {
  var element = DOM.getElementsByClassName("menu" + id)[0];
  if (DOM.contains(DOM.getElementsByClassName("menu" + id)[0])) {
    element.style.display = "block";
  }
  else {
    console.error("Invalid DOM or invalid ID entered for showMenu(" + DOM + ", " + id + ")");
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: FWIW, inline event attributes are bad for multiple reasons among which, weird reference chaining where a variable will first be checked as a property on the element and the document, leading to hard to debug bugs, it's also harder to do static analysis (or simply to understand where the event comes from) and some other drawbacks. So while it's obviously up to you, you would be probably a lot better with your event added from your JS script, using `addEventListener`.

Comment: "*`<button ontouchstart=…>`*"??? Why not use a regular `onclick` handler?